# Split a string variable and use only a section bash

Tags: bash, sed, word-wrap, cut

I have a Variable like below.

`1.1.0.1580308800316`

Is there a way to get 1.1.0 as a separate variable and 1580308800316 as a separate variable? Like `var1=1.1.0 and var2=1580308800316`

I tried the following code line which I could find.

`echo 1.1.0.1580308800316 | fold -w6`

But it didn't bring me the result I wanted.

``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though IMHO you could create 2 elements out of your text and could save in 2 elements of an array and then make use of that array items one by one, since OP insisted to have variables only, so you could use `cut` command for this one.

```
first_var=$(echo "1.1.0.1580308800316"  | cut -d'.' -f1-3)
second_var=$(echo "1.1.0.1580308800316"  | cut -d'.' -f4)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I appreciate your opinion. Actually this is a docker curl response for a docker image tag which I get from a JSON file. $first_var is actually a product version and the $second_var is just a timestamp. I wanted to separate both of them. The above worked. Once again. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 5):

It is possible with standard POSIX shell:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

version='1.1.0.1580308800316'

var1="${version%.*}"
var2="${version##*.}"

printf 'Version: %s\n' "$version"
printf 'Var1: %s\n' "$var1"
printf 'Var2: %s\n' "$var2"
```

Output:

```
Version: 1.1.0.1580308800316
Var1: 1.1.0
Var2: 1580308800316
```

Comment: I tried this method and this also worked. Thank you very much for your help :)